# php my admin my sql database and android studio failed to connect to local host

Tags: android, sql

This is the error I am getting and I am not sure why. This is the code I have for connecting to my local host. My IPv4 addresses is the ip address below for the base url. Is this correct? I really do not know what is causing this error. I have no errors in android studio and the apps run but crashes.

```
public class Common {

private static final String BASE_URL = "https://192.168.1.8";

public static CoffeeShopAPI getAPI()
{
    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(CoffeeShopAPI.class);
}
```

}

```
 019-11-02 13:17:01.706 4554-4554/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.8 (port 443) from /192.168.1.6 (port 59442) after 10000ms

 io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.8 (port 443) from /192.168.1.6 (port 59442) after 10000ms
```

Comment: `My IPv4 addresses is the ip address below for the base url. Is this correct?` How should we know? We cannot look at or in your computers or in your network.

Comment: Yes I understand but can you please explain where you think the issue might be

Comment: `failed to connect to /192.168.1.8 (port 443)` Well you should comment first. Why this ip address?

Comment: @blackapps that is the ipv4 address listed in command prompt on my computer

Comment: A firewall could prevent connection. Or a virus scanner.

Comment: i turned off both firewalls i am not sure